# iOS add subviews to a scroll view with dynamic heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, subviews

The problem I am forcing is:
I have 1 big scrollView and I have to add to it 5 subviews programmatically
when I don't know what heights the sub views will have :(

Is there some API to do so ?
or I have to count the subviews heights manually and add them with `CGRectMake`
based by calculated sizes?

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say you dont know what heights the subviews are ? (content is fetched from web & needs waiting ? ) 

Use CGRectGetMaxY(rect) method to find the maxY point & set the frame origin of next subview.

Comment: what exactly is the issue with adding together a few `frame.size.height`'s ??? if you need an API to do this you are in for some hard times later on

Comment: I would go to `CGRectMake` solution but I would subclass it to make all this reusable. Another option is to find some vertical linear layout manager implementation and use it to calculate size an layout views. Then your view hierarchy will look like `UIScrollView -> LayoutManager -> All other views`

Comment: The problem is:some of the subViews are text and they can vary in its height, and yes I am fetching data from webService.
and I can't make them scrollables -> they want to lay them on 1 scroll view and have nice spaces between the textViews etc , and I have no idea how to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use Auto Layout. If you add your subviews to the scroll view using internal constraints, then these constraints can determine not only the distance of the subviews from one another but also the distance from the imaginary content view that surrounds them. The scroll view then uses the size of the content view as its `contentSize`, and the whole thing becomes scrollable. And this works despite the fact that you don't know the heights of any of the views, which is exactly what you're after.

Comment: For example, look at this code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p362scrollViewInCode2/ch20p670scrollViewInCode2/ViewController.m You will notice that I'm adding a whole bunch of UILabel objects to the scroll view. But at no time do I ever ask the height of any of those UILabel objects! Yet the result is that you can scroll to any of them. That's because the `contentSize` is set automatically based on the constraints that I add as I add the labels.

Comment: Mang , Your my hero !!!! honestly I have tried the same approach from apple's page tutorials but some why it didn't work for me , the view got messed up so weird , and your link made it clear as reboiled water !!! thanks so so so so so so so much !!!